# systemd start at boot but it is stopped

Tags: shell, shell-script, systemd, sh

I have developed a shell script :

```
#!/bin/sh
# do some treatment
for i in `seq 0 10000`;do
# do some treatment and create/write into log file
done
```

**NOTE: my script work manually perfectly without any error, it take about 58 minutes**

And I have created systemd files to launch it at boot and every 60 minutes:

myservice@.service:

```
[Unit]

Description=my script service
DefaultDependencies=no

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=myscript.sh > /dev/null 2>&1

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

myservice.timer:

```
[Unit]
Description=Announce every 60 minutes

[Timer]
OnUnitActiveSec=60m
AccuracySec=10s
Unit=myservice@.service

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

After that I have enabled the service and the timer

```
cd /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants && ln -s ../myservice@.service myservice@boot.service
cd /lib/systemd/system/timers.target.wants && ln -s ../myservice.timer
```

My problem is the script is launched at boot but it is stopped because the log file is created and it write some log data. When I check dmesg I have this log:

```
>[    4.074064] systemd[1]: Created slice system-myservice.slice.
>[    4.076893] systemd[1]: Starting my script service service...
>[    5.071797] systemd[1]: myservice@boot.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
>[    5.074470] systemd[1]: Failed to start my script service service.
>[    5.079797] systemd[1]: myservice@boot.service: Unit entered failed state.
>[    5.079849] systemd[1]: myservice@boot.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
>[   62.635246] systemd[1]: Starting my script service service...
>[   62.789533] systemd[1]: myservice@boot.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
>[   62.791783] systemd[1]: Failed to start my script service service.
>[   62.810654] systemd[1]: myservice@boot.service: Unit entered failed state.
>[   62.810725] systemd[1]: myservice@boot.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
>[  105.064250] systemd[1]: Starting my script service service...
>[  105.206430] systemd[1]: myservice@boot.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
>[  105.208561] systemd[1]: Failed to start my script service service.
>[  105.228600] systemd[1]: myservice@boot.service: Unit entered failed state.
>[  105.228669] systemd[1]: myservice@boot.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Also I have a problem when I try to launch it manually:

```
systemctl start myservice@*.service
[ 1194.443225] systemd[1]: Failed to start my script service service.
Job for myservice@boot.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status myservice@boot.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Here is the status of service:

```
systemctl status myservice@*.service
● myservice@boot.service - my script service service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/../myservice@.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-11-14 21:24:41 UTC; 1min 33s ago
  Process: 1910 ExecStart=myscript.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 (code=exited, status=2)
 Main PID: 1910 (code=exited, status=2)
```

Why I have such failure ?How can I fix this problem? I have tried many solution to fix that but still not working, I have tried to make service Type=idle, Type=simple, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says so in your status output:

```
Process: 1910 ExecStart=myscript.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 (code=exited, status=2)
```

This means that your script *was started*, but exited on its own, providing return code 2 to the OS.

A likely cause is that you did not specify the correct WorkingDirectory= or the correct User= to match your script's expectations. Another possible cause is that due to usage of DefaultDependencies=no, your script runs *too early* and is unable to e.g. access filesystems that aren't yet mounted or devices that aren't yet detected.

Note that the ExecStart= parameter **is not a shell command**; it does not support redirections and will simply pass them to the program as literal command-line arguments. Make sure your script does not treat these arguments as a fatal error. (If you want to prevent its stdout from being logged, use StandardOutput=null instead.)

Also note that .timer will not activate a unit that is already "active". If you're specifying RemainAfterExit=true, that means myscript.service will forever remain "active" after the first run, so it will never be re-triggered by the timer.

Comment: Good explanation, it works now, thank you a lot